# WSO2 ESB AMQ Connection Error

Tags: jms, amqp, wso2, wso2-esb

I am working with WSO2 ESB 4.7.0 and WSO2 MB 2.2.0.

I want to work with the concepts of publish and subscribe messages with JMS queues. For this I have made integration between WSO2 ESB and WSO2 MB by following the below link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB220/Integrating+WSO2+ESB

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the  document and tried to restart the ESB server but failed to start the server cause of the below error:

```
AMQConnection Unable to connect to broker at tcp://localhost:5672
org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:120)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:616)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:398)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:328)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.util.JMSUtil.createConnection(JMSUtil.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.createConnection(JMSMessageStore.java:717)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.getReadConnection(JMSMessageStore.java:634)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.newConsumer0(JMSMessageStore.java:1040)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.fetchInto(JMSMessageStore.java:284)
    at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.SamplingHandler.execute(SamplingHandler.java:67)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

How to overcome this error and start the ESB server successfully?

Need any further configuration in any of the files present in ESB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a port configuration issue.

The tutorial is mentioning to set the port of the two connection factories to **5673** in the *JDNI.properties* file of the ESB after applying a port offset for the Message Broker, yet you are getting an exception on port **5672** when trying to connect to the Message Broker. Make sure the two match.

In the Message Broker logs you should see something like this if you set the port offset to 1:

```
INFO {qpid.message.broker.listening} -  [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5673
```

Comment: thanks for  the replay @voicu can u please help me were and in which files i can change these settings and make the two port match...

Comment: @user4045063: _<MB_HOME>/repository/conf/carbon.xml_ for the port offset in the Message Broker, _<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/JNDI.properties_ for the ESB side. The [tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB220/Integrating+WSO2+ESB) you mentioned has these details.